# Beamer (with style) to Html5?

Tags: beamer, html, knitr

My organization require the use of a standardized powerpoint template for how slides should look, so I've written my own Beamer .sty (style file).

Then I write .Rnw-files in RStudio that I knit (knitr) to create pdf-slides that look like they should. The slides have more advanced layout than what just Markdown allows (corporate logos, fonts, color palettes etc.).

But I'm getting jelous of all the nice looking HTML5-presentations out there (reveal.js, DZslides, etc.).

Is there a way to go from advanced beamer (including .sty) to HTML5?

Or do I need to start from scratch and re-create the layout in the HTML5 environment and use Markdown somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: you'll almost certainly need to start from scratch. Converting TeX to HTML is certainly possible, but almost always focusses on persevering logical structure with the assumption that CSS can be added 'later' to deal with appearance. The two beasts are different, so what makes sense for TeX doesn't necessarily for HTML. In particular, you are not going to get anything like the look of a well-produced HTML presentation out of such a process, and as presentation is really about the visual will then spend almost certainly as long reworking what you've got as you would have on new material.